# Sql Server insert command adding "Â" to an NVarChar column

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql command as follows:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Currency] ([CurrencyID], [Description], [Symbol]) 
VALUES (N'7418fe34-1abc-4189-b5f1-e638a34af1a1', N'GBP', N'£')
```

When I run this against the database, it inputs the last column as 'Â£' rather than '£'. I have come across this before but can't for the life of me remember how to fix it!

Any ideas?

Thanks.

### UPDATE

Funnilty enough, if I copy and paste that line from my sql file into sql man stud, then it inserts fine. So I think there is something wrong with my sql file, and a possible character in it that I cant see?

### UPDATE

The sql script has the following to insert the euro symbol:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Currency] ([CurrencyID], [Description], [Symbol])
VALUES (N'c60b1e0c-289a-4a0a-8c7d-30a490cbb7a8', N'EUR', N'€')
```

And it outputs "â‚¬" in the database for the last column

### UPDATE

Ok, I have now copy and pasted my full sql file into Sql Server and run it, and it now inserts everything fine. So why does this issue arise only when I run my ".sql" file?

### UPDATE

Another update! If I view the ".sql" file in Visual Studio it looks fine, however if I open it within notepad, the bogus characters appear!

Comment: so, what type is the column `Symbol` in the database?

Comment: Probably a collation setting of the database or the column?

Comment: It is an NVarChar, and I have not touched the collation. Surely the normal collation (Latin1 general) should handle a "£" properly.

Comment: Most likely your .sql file is a UTF-8 file, but whatever program you were using that was reading it was interpreting it differently. Were you opening it in SSMS, or in some other program (such as, say, sqlcmd)?

Comment: So what happens if you: open notepad -> paste the contents of you sql file -> save the notepad file as a sql file -> run the new sql file?

Comment: @mouters Your edit removed a useful update.

Comment: @hvd I ran it from a bat file

Comment: @mouters I pasted it into notepad, and saved it as a new file and ran it, the "£" was fixed but it messed up all the foreign currencies that have dodgy characters

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) // [The Notepad file encoding problem, redux](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx)

Comment: @eyeballpaul Using osql? sqlcmd? Something else?

Comment: @hvd sorry, I used a bat file to run sqlcmd

Comment: @eyeballpaul In that case, try the `-f` option to specify the file encoding. UTF-8 should be `-f 65001`. IIRC, the default is to use the OEM code page, which is almost never what you want.

Comment: @hvd sorry I don't quite understand. My ".sql" file looks perfect when I open it in Visual Studio, but causes this issue when I run it using sqlcmd, what is it exactly you are telling me to do?

Comment: @eyeballpaul It's an option you pass to sqlcmd, so instead of `sqlcmd -i yourfile.sql`, you'd use `sqlcmd -i yourfile.sql -f 65001`.

Comment: @hvd Ah ok, I'll give that a go.

Comment: @hvd, superb, that has worked I think, post it up as an answer and I will mark as answer

Comment: @eyeballpaul Glad it helped, it's an answer now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(From the comments)

The file is saved as UTF-8, but sqlcmd is reading it using the wrong code page. Adding `-f 65001` to the options tells sqlcmd to read it as an UTF-8 file.